# Consumir api com laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, framework

Estou procurando na documentação do Laravel, em varios lugares , mas ainda não tive sucesso estou procurando algum lugar que tem um tutorial como consumir uma api com laravel!

Comment: Qual API você quer consumir?

Comment: a minha mesmo , ja consumi ela utilizando ionic , e bem simples tem 3 campos só `id` ,`email`,`senha` com o passport ,mas ainda não testei no laravel , ja usei no postman e no ionic 3

Answer (score 0):

Independente de qual seu Framework, antes de consumir algo é necessário compreender o que é de fato consumir uma API. Isso facilitará.

Veja:

Uma API nada mais é do que um conjunto de rotas (links) publico (ou não) que fornecerão dados em um formato específico (ultimamente JSON).

Perceba que, em outras palavras, você precisa fazer seu Laravel acessar links e interpretar o retorno deles.

Sendo assim, você precisa de idéias para fazer requisições através do seu sistema. Para isso, temos algumas opções:

1. Chamada CURL pura com PHP
   http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/curl.examples-basic.php
2. Chamada CURL via Shell_exec (para linux);
   https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/
3. Algum package que abstraia o processo: https://medium.com/laravel-5-the-right-way/using-guzzlehttp-with-laravel-1dbea1f633da

Independe da escolha, você estará de todo jeito fazendo uma requisição para outro servidor, no caso o que fornece o serviço da API que você precisa.

Em termos de arquitetura, acredito que o ideal para isso é você não utilizar o próprio controller, mas sim uma camada de Serviços para este processo.

Um exemplo disso são sistemas que possuem integrações com Mercado Livre, tenho uma aplicação assim e, neste caso, montei um serviço que é responsável por todas as tratativas que envolvam a API. Isso facilita o processo pois, uma vez feito, eu não preciso mais pensar em como a API funciona de fato, apenas utilizar meu serviço montado que abstrai o processo.

Alternativa 1:

1. Faça o Serviço que faça as chamadas na API terceira;
2. Cria alguma Rota e Controller para chamar este serviço;
3. Inclua no Crontab do S.O para que fique chamando este link de tempo em tempo;

Alternativa 2:

1. Faça o Serviço que faça as chamadas na API terceira;
2. Programe no schedule do Laravel para que execute o serviço de tempo em tempo;

Alternativa 3:

1. No caso de notificações da API terceira, cria uma rota que receba os dados dela;
2. Configure no fornecedor da API para chamar sua rota.

Comment: Sim , eu entendo como funciona ja, ate ja criei utilizando passport , autenticaçao e validação com tokens ,ja consumi utilizando o no ionic 3 , agora quero consumir ela no laravel

Comment: Confere se consegui esclarecer um pouco mais